# Use browser as viewer for ggplot2 via R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm wonder if it is possible when plotting in R with ggplot2 to send your plots to the browser to be viewed?

Comment: You can save your plots to a file with `ggsave`, open the file in a browser, and refresh whenever you update the plot. You can also use knitr to convert an rmarkdown document with ggplots to HTML and view in the browser. Simply replacing the R plotting window with your browser is probably not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way for **Windows** users, who have .html files associated with a browser like Firefox or Chrome:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplotToBrowser <- function(p) {
  ggsave(filename = tf_img <- tempfile(fileext = ".svg"), plot = p)
  html <- sprintf('<html><body><img src="%s"></body></html>', paste0("file:///", tf_img))
  cat(html, file = tf_html <- tempfile(fileext = ".html"))
  shell.exec(tf_html) # or system(sprintf("open %s", tf_html))
}
p <- ggplot(diamonds[1:100, ], aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point(alpha = .1)
ggplotToBrowser(p)
```

On a **Mac**, you want to replace `shell.exec(tf_html)` by `system(sprintf("open %s", tf_html))` as proposed by @baptiste.

Comment: Nice I'm a mac user tho is there a way to modify this to work for a mac?

Comment: @moku I'm sure there is, but as I don't have any Apple products, I don't know it. Let's wait for another answer. :)

Comment: Ha fair enough I was looking around to see there was a comparable shell.exec command for R on a mac... can't find anything.

Comment: `system(sprintf("open %s", tf_html))` should do it

Comment: @lukeA add a version with baptiste fix for mac and i'll give you the answer!